# UILabel lineBreakMode clip doesn't clip text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have a UILabel and I've set it's line break mode to clip, but I don't see the ... at the end, instead it just truncates/cut the text at the point where it overflows. Is there any other part of the code that I need to set?

Here's how I am doing it:

```
  [self.newsFeedHeadingTitle_ setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set it to "UILineBreakModeTailTruncation" if you want the dots at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to set the number of lines the UILabel is allowed to have. Like this `[myLabel setNumberOfLines:x]` where x is the number of lines you want to have. If you set x to zero , the label can have as many lines as it needs. By default, that value it's 1 so that is why your label does not break the text into multiple lines.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: well , there you have it. You must set it to 2 or more in order to clip the text. Or 0 if you are not sure how many lines you will have.

Comment: I only want it to have one line

Comment: Ooooh...I got it now , sorry , I didn't understand the question first. you need to set it to `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` instead of `UILineBreakModeClip` in order to see the dots

Answer (score 0):

If you're using plain `NSString`-objects on a `UILabel`, `myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;` should work.

If you are using `NSAttributedString`-objects with a `NSParagraphStyle`, use `myParagraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;`

Setting the linebreak-mode of the paragraph-style worked for me.