# How to add dots to UILabel if text does not fit frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a cell with multiline UILabels, but when the text's label does not fit the frame, no dots are shown. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you really need to add a bounty to this. There are hundreds of answers to this sort of question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302165/uilabel-linebreakmode-clip-doesnt-clip-text and https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=UILabel+lineBreakMode+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=cQiiUsPpBKTK0QXZuoHoDA simple google search.

Comment: @Popeye i tried to fix this problem according to previous answers, but it doesn't help me.
PS: My label's property "numberOfLines" set to "2", if it's equal to "1", it's works.

Comment: numberOfLines is 1 by default. Try to set it 0 if you dont know the exact numberOfLines and use sizeToFit method of UILable.

Comment: @iProgrammer I have fixed maximum number of lines - 2. And sizeToFit works awful all the time.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Have you tried this?

**Prior Swift 5**:

```
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

**Swift 5**:

```
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```

Prior **iOS6** use `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation`

Comment: I think the correct option is `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`. The one you mention in your answer is deprecated.

Comment: I tried to use NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail, not UILineBreakModeTailTruncation.

Comment: That won't work for multiline labels. The `lineBreakMode` should be `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` or `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`.

Comment: @brunobasas Thanks for editing. Anyway, some readers may find useful the original answer as it may depend on ios version. It'd be nice to keep both alternatives in the answer :)

Comment: I have another similar question with my explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903975/uilabel-with-numberoflines-and-linebreakmode

Answer (score 13):

If your are using **AttributedStrings**, be aware that you'll have to set the `.lineBreakMode` to your `NSMutableParagraphStyle`.

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail

// Add paragraphStyle to attributes, create AttributedString...
```

Comment: Nice shot dude !

Answer (score 5):

For **swift 2.0** it will be:

```
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false;
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
```

For **swift 4.0** it will be:

```
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false;
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
```

Comment: in Swift 4 just need to give 'b' small. like(yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false;
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail)

Answer (score 3):

If the linebreakmode doesnt work foryou, another option is to actually calculate the length your string is going to take and if it is going to be longer than the label size, add "..." yourself.

You will have to play with the following code to handle for multi line (but the idea is similar)

For example, Take you label (for example detailLabel)

```
UILabel* detailLabel = cell.detailTextLabel;
CGSize expectedDetailLabelSize = [detailLabel.text sizeWithFont:detailLabel.font
                                             constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                 lineBreakMode:detailLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

Comment: I know this solution, but at the same time I hope there is more simple way.)

Answer (score 0):

**For SWIFT 3+**

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.0 Example:

```
extension String {
  /*
   Truncates the string to the specified length number of characters and appends an optional trailing string if longer.
   - Parameter length: Desired maximum lengths of a string
   - Parameter trailing: A 'String' that will be appended after the truncation.

   - Returns: 'String' object. 
  */
  func trunc(length: Int, trailing: String = "…") -> String {
    return (self.count > length) ? self.prefix(length) + trailing : self
  }
}    

let str = "I might be just a little bit too long".truncate(10)
```

ref. link [String Truncate](https://gist.github.com/budidino/8585eecd55fd4284afaaef762450f98e)