# UILabel with numberOfLines and lineBreakMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I am working on a project that has to support both iOS6 and iOS7. My problem is it works different on different systems. I'm trying to create UILabel with number of lines equal to 2, but when I set it's line break mode to NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail it works different.

Explanation (numberOfLines = 2, text = @"long teeexxxttt"):

```
    iOS7                    iOS6
      NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
 ----------              ----------
|long      |            |long      |
|teeeexxxtt|            |teeeexxxtt|
 ----------              ----------

     NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail
 ----------              ----------
|long      |            |long te...|
|teeeexx...|            |          |
 ----------              ----------
     ^                       ^
     |                       |
  correct                incorrect - shows only one line
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: u can use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping mode if want the content for two line in ios7

Comment: Make sure your label frame is not getting changed, check it . can you print your label frame for both version?\

Comment: @Virussmca it's getting changed (but it is the same for both iOS), is it the problem? I set these properties after changing frame.

Comment: @CoolMonster At the same time I need "..." at the end.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich: can you print your label frame for both version after setting properties?

Comment: may be in ios 6 your label height is getting small.

Comment: @Virussmca For both iOS I get "200x50" in logs.

Comment: can you please upload code?

Comment: @Virussmca http://rghost.net/51374206 - my class (.h and .m) where I use this UILabel.

Comment: @Virussmca I have found the issue, the problem is UILabel's NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail won't work with custom font.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich: than put it as answer and accept it, so it helps to other also.

Comment: @Virussmca I've just found another my class where the same code works perfectly, the only deference is I use autoresizing there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is iOS6 and prior won't update multiline UILabels with custom UIFont and NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail, but you can archive the same result by using autoresizing or autolayout.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had the same problem.  I found that with constraints I had to set the preferred width to get the ellipsis to behave properly:

```
yourLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width;
```

[UILable.preferredMaxLayoutWidth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth)

Comment: Fantastic! You saved my day... the last line of my uilabel was always AWOL... and this solution helped resolve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Swift 2.1

```
yourLabel.text = "your text"
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
yourLabel.sizeToFit()
```